# Save BitmapImage to local image file in uwp?

Tags: uwp

I have a image control in my app, and already set its Source.

How to save the image to a local image file?

I tried the following code, but not work.

```
var saveFile = new FileSavePicker();
            saveFile.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            saveFile.FileTypeChoices.Add("jpeg", new List<string> { ".jpeg" });
            saveFile.SuggestedFileName = MasterMenuItem.Title + " - " + MasterMenuItem.AlbumArtistsString;
            StorageFile sFile = await saveFile.PickSaveFileAsync();
            try
            {
                if (sFile != null)
                {
                    Guid bitmapEncoderGuid = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;
                    IRandomAccessStream stream = await sFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.None);
                    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(bitmapEncoderGuid, stream);
                    BitmapImage bi = MasterMenuItem.Cover as BitmapImage;
                    WriteableBitmap wb = null;
                    wb = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromContent(bi.UriSource);
                    Stream pixelStream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
                    byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
                    await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                              (uint)wb.PixelWidth,
                              (uint)wb.PixelHeight,
                              96.0,
                              96.0,
                              pixels);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();

                    stream.Dispose();
                    pixelStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working method from one of my application.

Basically i am converting the `Image` Control to `RenderTargetBitmap` and then saving the image using `FileSavePicker`.

If do not want to use the `Image` Control but want to save the `Source` itself, you need to save a `SoftwareBitmap` while rendering the `Image` control and then you an use that to save the `Image`. Example is [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#save-a-softwarebitmap-to-a-file-with-bitmapencoder)

```cs
    private async void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await _bitmap.RenderAsync(myImageSource);    //-----> This is my ImageControl.

        var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "Card" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        StorageFile savefile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (savefile == null)
            return;

        var pixels = await _bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await savefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await
            BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
            byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                    BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                    (uint)_bitmap.PixelWidth,
                                (uint)_bitmap.PixelHeight,
                                    200,
                                    200,
                                    bytes);

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a round-trip solution that I came up with for handling images in UWP.

Also, I had the need to encode and decode from base-64.

The following code is the only way to do it if you don't want to call the FileOpenPicker.

Also, mind you: if you don't call the picker, your options on where to save the file are limited, which is why I default to the user's download directory.

The secret is to always create a [**WriteableBitmap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2), in the first place.  It can be easily bound to XAML components and also stored.  Do not create a BitmapImage, do not create an image source... just always deal in WriteableBitmap... especially if you are producing an application that requires that you read and write images, frequently.

Honestly, this was so much easier in WinForms.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;

namespace Images
{
    public static class ImageHelper
    {
        public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> TestImage()
        {

            // example base64-encoded icon in PNG format at 24x24, 32 bit color
            string base64str = "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";

            // First load the image from the base64 string
            var img = await LoadImageFromBase64(base64str);

            // Now test round-trip Base64 to Base64
            string sTest = await SaveImageToBase64(img);

            img = await LoadImageFromBase64(sTest);

            // now save the round-trip image
            var accTok = await SaveImageToFile("checkbox-round-trip.png", img);

            // now load, round-trip, from disk.
            img = await LoadImageFromFile(accTok, true);

            return img;
        }


        public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> LoadImageFromBase64(string base64str)
        {
            try
            {
                var decodedBin = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(base64str);

                var readStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

                await readStream.WriteAsync(decodedBin);
                readStream.Seek(0);

                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(readStream);

                var workBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
                readStream.Seek(0);

                await workBmp.SetSourceAsync(readStream);
                return workBmp;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<string> SaveImageToBase64(WriteableBitmap workBmp)
        {
            try
            {
                var writeStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, writeStream);

                // saving to a straight 32 bpp PNG, the dpiX and dpiY values are irrelevant, but also cannot be zero. 
                // We will use the default "since-the-beginning-of-time" 96 dpi.
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)workBmp.PixelWidth, (uint)workBmp.PixelHeight, 96, 96, workBmp.PixelBuffer.ToArray());

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
                writeStream.Seek(0);

                var proxyStream = writeStream.AsStreamForRead();
                byte[] b = new byte[proxyStream.Length];

                await proxyStream.ReadAsync(b, 0, (int)proxyStream.Length);

                proxyStream.Dispose();

                return (string)CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(b.AsBuffer());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> LoadImageFromFile(string fileName, bool isToken = false)
        {
            try
            {
                var xc = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList;
                StorageFile decodedBin;

                if (!isToken)
                {
                    decodedBin = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    decodedBin = await xc.GetFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.AccessCache.AccessCacheOptions.None);
                }

                var readStream = await decodedBin.OpenReadAsync();

                var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(readStream);
                var workBmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);

                readStream.Seek(0);

                await workBmp.SetSourceAsync(readStream);

                readStream.Dispose();
                return workBmp;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<string> SaveImageToFile(string fileName, WriteableBitmap workBmp)
        {
            try
            {
                var writeStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, writeStream);

                // saving to a straight 32 bpp PNG, the dpiX and dpiY values are irrelevant, but also cannot be zero. 
                // We will use the default "since-the-beginning-of-time" 96 dpi.
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)workBmp.PixelWidth, (uint)workBmp.PixelHeight, 96, 96, workBmp.PixelBuffer.ToArray());

                await encoder.FlushAsync();

                writeStream.Seek(0);

                var dl = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                var imgFileOut = await dl.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

                var fileProxyStream = writeStream.AsStreamForRead();

                await fileProxyStream.CopyToAsync(imgFileOut);
                await imgFileOut.FlushAsync();

                fileProxyStream.Dispose();
                imgFileOut.Dispose();

                var xc = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList;

                return xc.Add(dl);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```